# how can i build a cheap linear actuator

Tags: motor, raspberry-pi, linear, home-automation, actuator

I need a linear actuator for my IOT project but how do i make one and how do i use python to control it? i saw videos of people making it with glue sticks and servos but i don't think it will be effective.
[image]

And i am making a auto feeder so any actuator that open and close is ok.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to understand what you are actually trying to ask. First you need a linear actuator, then you need Python to control it, which is totally unrelated to building a linear actuator. Then you saw people doing it but don't think it's effective (why?). And finally you need any actuator that open and closes, which could very well be rotary actuator with a flap. For an auto feeder I'd even consider a wheel where every section can hold a small amount and turning it will make small chunks of food come out.

Comment: I'm looking for most effective to open and close my feeder it doesn't have to be a linear actuator but i want to control it using my server side python script. Sorry about my post i'm new to electronics.

Comment: "my feeder".. ? And what is it exactly? Cat feeder? Fish feeder? Paper feeder to printer?

Comment: I'm sorry about that. It is a Bird Feeder.

Comment: This is more of a mechanical design question than an electrical/electronic one. Furthermore, it is far too broad unless you provide some indication of what kind of speed, force, travel distance and accuracy your application requires.

Comment: I want to build a internet controlled bird feeder . Some thing like this but a bit more smaller https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/outdoor-living/detailpages/wingscapes/B0083H9HBU-1.jpg.

Comment: I want to build a internet controlled bird feeder . Some thing like this but a bit more smaller https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/outdoor-living/detailpages/wingscapes/B0083H9HBU-1.jpg. I have have html webpage. IN my webpage when i press i button i want to it to send a message to my raspberry pi board which will execute a python script to feed my bird.

Comment: Due to ambiguity in English a bird feeder could also be a cat feeder (ie. feeding birds to a cat).

Comment: That was no a very useful comment(ie. Try typing bird feeder in google and see what you find).

Answer (score 2):

You can procure a linear servo as used in RC gadgets. Then you just need to feed it a pulse train in the usual format.

[image]